# Java JDBC how to pass date in

Tags: java, jdbc

How can I take the the date value from my html, then add it to the database.

I tried many ways but its not working. I keep getting back a NULL value in the database or an error message "java.text.dateformat.parse(unknown source)"

HTML:

```
Date Of Birth: <input type="date" name="dob">
```

JAVA:

```
String date = request.getParameter("dob");


Date dob1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"));

 PreparedStatement createUser = connection.prepareStatement(
                  "INSERT into users (dob1)" +
                 " VALUES ( ?)");{


                 createUser.setDate(1, (java.sql.Date) dob1);


                 int newUser = createUser.executeUpdate(); 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String date = request.getParameter("dob");


Date dob1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"));
```

This second line is wrong.  Change to

```
Date dob1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy")).parse(date);
```

### edit

By the comment you're using the wrong date format. Use it instead.

```
Date dob1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")).parse(date);
```

Comment: I still get the errror : " java.text.parseexception: unparseable date: " 1995-06-25" "

Comment: You're using the wrong date format, use "yyyy-MM-dd" instead.  Added to my answer.